# sql query group by one in join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I've a couple of tables:

```
--> task: task_id, status, datetime, code
--> task_action: action_id, task_id, action_type, action_details, action_datetime
```

And I've an action_type:  `ASSIGNED` which has this JSON as its `action_type` : `{"assigned_to": "some_email_id"}`

So what I want are all the tasks with all columns which have `status` in `task table` as: `PROCESSING`

and there corresponding `action_type` is `ASSIGNED` with latest datetime, (A task can have multiple `ASSIGNED` action_type)
and `assigned_to` email id is queried with.

only the latest ASSIGNED action_type should be matched with given email id in `assigned_to`
This is one of the queries I tried with:

```
select task_action.task_id
     , max(action_datetime) as dt
     , action_details
as adt 
  FROM task_action
  JOIN task 
    on task.task_id = task_action.task_id 
 WHERE action_type = 'ASSIGNED' 
   and task.status = 'PROCESSING' 
   and JSON_VALUE(adt, '$.assigned_to') = 'someEmail'   
 GROUP 
    BY task_id
```

Obviously, this does not work..I guess there is something minor am missing.

Comment: MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server? You have tagged your question with both tags.

Comment: Yes. First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: @sachsure, If i consider you are using sql but its still hard to answer without knowning you json value. I have create sqlfiddle from my understanding have look here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/608f2/6

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 5.7, you can use this:

```
WHERE ... adt->>'$.assigned_to' = 'someEmail'
```

If you just use `->` then the value has literal double-quotes. Use `->>` to get the bare value.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are searching for a row in task_action with maximum datetime, not just the maximum value. That is a bit more complicated to express in SQL. You can search for a task_action where no other task_action with a greater datetime exists:

```
WITH assigned_action as (
  select 
    task_id,
    action_datetime, 
    action_details 
  from 
    task_action 
  where
    action_type='ASSIGNED' and 
    JSON_VALUE(action_details, '$.assigned_to')='someEmail'
)

SELECT 
   t.task_id, 
   a.action_datetime as dt, 
   a.action_details as adt 
FROM 
  task t inner join (
    select *
    from 
      assigned_action a1
    where not exists (
      select * 
      from assigned_action a2
      where 
        a2.action_datetime > a1.action_datetime and
        a2.task_id = a1.task_id 
    )
  ) a on t.task_id = a.task_id
WHERE 
  t.status='PROCESSING'
```